# Iterating VCFilter tree in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I have a VS2013 addin that I'm porting to VS2017 and I find myself unable to iterate over the filters in my project in the same way that works fine in 2013. This is my code:

```
public void OnSolutionLoaded()
{
    DTE2 dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
    foreach (Project lProject in dte.Solution.Projects)
    {
         if(lProject.Kind == vcContextGuids.vcContextGuidVCProject)
         {
             VCProject proj = (VCProject)lProject.Object;
             foreach (VCFilter childFilter in (IVCCollection)proj.Filters)
             {
                 RecurseFilters(childFilter);
             }
          }
     }
}

private void RecurseFilters(VCFilter filter)
{
    foreach(VCFilter childFilter in (IVCCollection)filter.Filters)
    {
        RecurseFilters(childFilter);
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in the recursion, it's never hit despite the fact that I have many filters within filters. The top level of filters are found fine.

I've checked for LSL, and that's not on. I'm running VS 15.1.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The above code works as expected until you add a solution folder, then the recursion no longer works. I assume this is a bug as this is different to the behaviour in VS2013

[image: Example of breaking solution folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 15.1 still has a bug in vc filters when projects are loaded from cache (see 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/faster-c-solution-load-with-vs-15/ 
how to enable/disable vc project cache).

The bug will be fixed in one of the coming VS updates (15.3 most likely).

And to explain the behavior you see: the project cache is not used when there is only one project in the solution, but as soon as there are two or more (and solution folder counts as a project), desktop vc projects are using different implementation which reads from cache instead of loading msbuild project.

So as a workaround for now, please set Tools - Options - Text Editor - C/C++ - Experimental - 'Enable Faster Project Load' to false

Comment: Sadly I still get the same issue even with faster project loading disabled.

Comment: And now it's working. No idea why, possibly due to a reboot. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it has child filters on the top level of filters. like this:

[image]

If you have the filters like above, you can hit the breakpoint in the recursion.(the demo is created by visual studio 2017 version 15.1) like this:

[image]

Comment: If I create a new C++ project it works as expected, but with my existing 2013 project I've migrated over it still doesn't traverse the hierarchy. I only get the top level filters.

Comment: And if I create a new 2013 project and import it into 2017 it works fine, so there's something odd about my particular project

Comment: OK, found the issue, it's solution folders. As soon as you add one of those it breaks the tree iteration.

Comment: I am glad to know that you find the issue, Do you resolve it or encounter any issue?

Comment: It's broken, I've just narrowed the repro down. I could refactor my solution to remove all solution folders, but I'd really rather not.